# Icecast Updating title metadata

Tags: icecast, multer-s3, audiostreamer

I've been playing with Icecast with Ezstream for a while and found this error while uploading a song.

I've been using multer-s3 to upload songs into s3 and read them from a mounted port on a server. The problem comes when last song that was uploaded has changed the title metadata of every song.

I assumed that the title metadata was grabbed by icecast and ezstream by filename but in this case it is injecting and prepending data for everysong by an unknown source.

So it should be giving "the new law --- daybreak" but it's injecting "Marshmello & Bastille -". Also, I've checked the filenames and they all are without the prepended string.

I've been reading the [Server Stats docs](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/server-stats.html) for injection and saw that title is "Metadata set by source client". Which makes me think is probably Ezstream injecting it but I haven't added it into the ezstream config files.

If you have any ideas on what would be? I appreciate any hints

[image]

Comment: check the ID3v1/ID3v2 data on that file. It might be reading that.

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver. You were right there was some metadata added into the file that was added automatically into the other files. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out ez-stream reads ID3 metadata. Which is a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Also, I've added <metadata_format>@s@</metadata_format> to my ezstream_mp3.xml to make sure it only runs the filename. https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ezstream/ezstream.1.en.html